# Django: ValueError at /save_page/ - invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'My World'

Tags: python, django, wiki

I am simply trying to save the data in the POST array to the database but this error arises.
Here is my view in which the error is located:

```
    def save_page(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':

            if "title" in request.POST and "content" in request.POST and request.POST["title"]:

                c = {}
                c.update(csrf(request))
                try:

                    article = Article.objects.get(pk=request.POST["title"])
                    article.content = request.POST["content"]
                except Article.DoesNotExist:
                    #the error arises here
                    article = Article(request.POST["title"], request.POST["content"])
                    article.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("Wikipedia/"+request.POST["title"]+"/")
                return render_to_response("create_page.html", c)
```

here is the model Article

```
    class Article(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

In my input fields, I'm simply giving "My World" as title. and "My friends" as content.

the complete traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/save_page/

Django Version: 1.5.5
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'Wiki')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:/Users/Zaid/PycharmProjects/Wikipedia\Wiki\views.py" in save_page
  61.                 article = Article.objects.get(pk=request.POST["title"])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in get
  143.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  395.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  669.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  687.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1271.                             can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_filter
  1202.                 connector)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in add
  71.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in prepare
  339.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  322.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  555.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /save_page/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'My World'
```

Comment: Can you give the complete traceback?

Comment: I see why you were reluctant to put it in the first place :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't specify a PK in your model, your Article's PK is the Django default; an  autoincremented integer (which you can refer to by either 'id' or 'pk'). Hence, when you query

```
article = Article.objects.get(pk=request.POST["title"])
```

you got the above error, as Django expects an integer for the PK. You either want to:

- add `primary_key=True` to the `title` field definition (underlying table needs to be recreated then, no code modification needed)
- add a `unique=True` to the `title` field definition and query with `get(title=request.POST["title"])`, unique constraint must be created on db level

You can of course query by title, without the additional unique constraint, but it may lead to errors in future if the same title is present on two models and you lookup via .get().

Answer (score 0):

You need to check URL in your template.
you need to pass the integer id to url {{user.id}} because url need to have integer value in template.
Ex.  url:-  /polls/{{user.id}}/
Hope this will work for others.